# Cadastrando dados de formulario com inputs de nomes iguais PHP

Tags: php, mysql, formulário

**Encontro-me a:**

- *implementar um formulario*
- *este possui vários inputs com o mesmo nome*
- *preciso de inserir os dados na base de dados*

**Pretendo de momento:**

- *criar um registo para cada utilizador da plataforma*
- *o formulário tem vários campos que ligam às várias entradas da base de dados*

  ```
  <div class="form nome_ch">
      <label for="nome_ch">Nome</label>
      <input type="text" name="nome_ch[]" id="nome_ch">
  </div>
  <div class="form cargo_ch">
      <label for="cargo_ch">Cargo</label>
      <input type="text" name="cargo_ch[]" id="cargo_ch">
  </div>
  <div class="form telefone_ch">
      <label for="telefone_ch">Telefone</label>
      <input type="text" name="telefone_ch[]" id="telefone_ch">
  </div>
  <div class="form email_ch">
      <label for="email_ch">E-mail</label>
      <input type="text" name="email_ch[]" id="email_ch">
  </div>
  <div class="form nascimento_ch">
      <label for="nascimento_ch">Nascimento</label>
      <input type="text" name="nascimento_ch[]" id="nascimento_ch">
  </div>
  ```

**Não sei como faço para:**

- *inserir na base de dados*

Existem vários **parâmetros do formulário** que ligam a **variáveis** ou **parâmetros** com *nomes idênticos*

Comment: No php você pega os dados $_POST['nome_ch'], ele vai ser um array como enviado no html name="nome_ch[]". Não tem problema ter vários inputs com mesmo nome se eles tiverem indicados como array no html pelo símbolo [].

Comment: sim, mas a minha duvida é que são 5 campos e nao só 1

Comment: Então é exatamente isso, se você enviar 2 inputs com name="nome_ch[]", nomes iguais, você vai pegar os 2 inputs no php  pegando eles pelo $_POST['nome_ch'], e vai receber um array com os 2 elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
ex:

<div class="form nome_ch">
    <label for="nome_ch">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="data[nome_ch]" id="nome_ch">
</div>

...

<div class="form nascimento_ch">
    <label for="nascimento_ch">Nascimento</label>
    <input type="text" name="data[nascimento_ch]" id="nascimento_ch">
</div>
```

Controle php

```
<?php 

print_r($_POST['data']);

Isso fara com quer passe as informações pelo único vetor.


Logo apos crie a condição de banco

$servidornome = "localhost";
$usuario = "username";
$senha = "password";

$conn = new mysqli($servidornome, $usuario, $senha);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexão falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "conctado sucesso";

$sql = "INSERT INTO sua tabela (nome_ch ,... , nascimento_ch)
VALUES ('{$_POST['data']['nome_ch']}', ... , '{$_POST['data']['nascimento_ch']}')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "inserido com sucesso";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```